# Ember-cli deserialize array error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've a problem deserializing an array with ember-cli and ember data.
I've models such as:

```
Label=DS.Model.extend
   ..
   days:DS.hasMany('day')

Day = DS.Model.extend
    hours: DS.attr()
```

The received JSON is:

```
labels:[
  {
   id: 1
   days:[{
      hours: [1,10, 33, 44,55,21]
   }]
  }
]
```

Now: I can properly manage `Embedded`record with `EmbeddedREcordMixin` but whenever an `hours` array is deserialized it is transformed into something like:

```
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
```

removing all original values.

I tryed defining a specific transform, or changing the relationship to `async` and normalizing the payload in a specific `labelSerializer`but nothing seems to have effect and I wasn't able to identify where the array is actually modified..

**Solution**

Finally, it was a problem of the received data set. Some record, with the same `id` was overwriting others, creating that misleading result.
With EmberData 1.0.0.beta8, no ArrayTransform is needed. Just plain `DS.attr()` did the job.

**EDIT:**

I've tried the same implementation on a non ember-cli application and it worked fine. I used EmbeddedRecordsMixin in the LabelSerializer to handle day embedded hasMany relation, as well as customized the normalizePayload and extractArray functions in order to fix small problems with `ids` etc..
But I'm quite new to Ember-cli, I'm not sure if I'm missing something. There is a need of special configurations in order to use ActiveModelAdapter, and the EmbeddedRecordsMixin?

**EDIT2**
Invalidate all about edit1...

**EDIT3**
After more testings, it is not a problem of Ember-cli.
When I test the deserialization through store.pushPayload() any manipulations of the JSON done in the `labelSerializer#normalizePaylod` or `labelSerializer#extractArry` works as expected.
Instead, when connecting to a remote server, the result array of values is a set of 0 and 1s.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Ember-Cli and Ember Data. I solved it like this:

I created a file called **array.js** in the **transforms** folder of my Ember-cli project.
(you can call the file what ever you like)

**transforms/array.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return serialized;
  },

  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
  }
});
```

Then in my model, I did this:

**somemodel.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    listOfSomething: DS.attr('array') //same name as the transform-file you created
});
```

Check out the Ember CLI documentation [Using modules and the resolver](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules)

**Edit**

After taking a close look at your example, I see that the JSON is not on the correct format that Ember expects. If you check out the [Ember Documentation on relationship between models](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships) your JSON should look something like this:

```
labels:[
  {
   id: 1
   days:[1]
  }
]

days: [
    {
        id: 1,
        hours: [1, 10, 33, 44, 55, 21]
    }
]
```

Comment: I've already tried with this but the result is the same. Within the array transform I receive the correct array and return the correct array, everything seems ok. But then, don't know where that same array is changed into a 0s and 1s array...I followed the ember-data functions a but I didn't found where the array's values are changed... Apply the transform solved your problem?

Comment: yes it solved my problem. I can save both strings, ints and objects in the array, and it works as expected.
Maybe it has something to do with the format of your JSON? See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, the JSON is a little mess. I don't have much control over the server API. I fixed that using `EmbeddedRecordMixin` in order to handle `days` hasMany relationshio has embedded, and customized the `labelSerializer#normalizePayload` and `labelSerializer#extractArray` to assign `ids` where needed. Just noticed I forgot to mention, but I tried this implementation in plain EmberApp (no ember-cli) and it works well, giving me the array of hours as expected. I edited the question accordingly. Can be somehow an `ember-cli` issue? Maybe a misconfiguration of some EmberData parameter?

Comment: Then I do not think I have anything else to contribute in solving your problem... Maybe you can try to update your ember-cli version? Ember data is now shipped with Ember cli. http://www.ember-cli.com/#ember-data

Comment: Ok, no, actually it isn't working in plain Ember needer. I just check more carefully. I'm going to try JSON modifications with a local server.